# How to remove attributes from url in VB scdript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vbscript

I am very new for VB script and Want few attributes from URL.

what i am trying here is :

```
strUrl = /PACS/Service.svc/PACS/0/95
```

The above one is my url. **I want to remove 0 and 95.**

My code :

```
If ((Instr(strUrl,"PACS") <> 0)) then
        string[] separateURL = strUrl.Split('?');
            LogToFile separateURL,"place.log"

    end if
```

But this is not working. Split is correct way or not I am not sure. Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working example.

I split url string by `/` and remove any empty strings and concat new string, but without two last elements.

```
Dim strUrl As String, separatedURL, newUrl As String, newstr
strUrl = "/PACS/Service.svc/PACS/0/95"

If ((InStr(strUrl, "PACS") <> 0)) Then
    separatedURL = Split(strUrl, "/")
    ReDim Preserve separatedURL(UBound(separatedURL) - 2)
    newUrl = "/"

    For Each urlPart In separatedURL
        If urlPart <> "" Then
            newUrl = newUrl + urlPart + "/"
        End If
    Next

    strUrl = newUrl

End If
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am trying this but getting "Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401'" in seprateURL line. Also I want to store in same strUrl.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize this was vbscript, I thought it was vb. Updated answer.